# Blender cycles baking causes problems mainly on character face

Tags: texturing, baking, normal-map

So I've been looking for a solution to get my character to look something similar to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN7I24t8Oec

I've dealt with this problem for weeks now but I can't find a solution to it, whether that be to add a cage, changing the UV coordinates multiple times and packing it afterwards or to change the ray distance and margin, it's causing my face to look like it's leather or melting and it looks really terrifying:
[image: Shows where the problem is clearly]

Again I've checked through multiple stackexchange and blenderartists questions similar to this, asked for help on the blenderhelp reddit, got into a blender discord to try and solve this problem, but to no avail, just wanted to let you know also that after baking, I go into blender render and then turn on GLSL shading, add lights and switch to textured view to see this atrocious mess. Is there any way I can fix this? It's really bothering me since I also have another character that has the same exact problem.

If you need a file, I can't provide it due to reputation limits, so if you need I will be happy to show you the .blend file.

**It will expire in 5 months though.**

Comment: To share a file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the resulting link into the body of your question.

Comment: I see a Cycles material being used in Blender Render. That's the first red flag.

Comment: Sorry I'm replying so late, it was just a visual bug. The character is now deleted since it turned out to be a poor effort.